# Applet - Which will read/modify system files and execute system commands

Tags: java, ios, cross-browser, applet, cross-platform

I'm a beginner with java applets. I have developed few small desktop applications using core java ( Swing ). I need to build an applet which can do the following things -

1. Read a system file and modify it.
2. Create system file.
3. Execute a system command for setting some configuration of the client machine
4. Applet will download a file by running a system command. I need to check for the file size and plot download speed in graph.
5. Applet should run on all platforms ( MAC OSX, Linux, Windows, Android, IOS )

I have already developed this app using python and PyQT which is platform independent. So my app can be run on all platform but that requires PyQT and some dependencies to be installed on all platforms which is a difficult job. So we are opting for java applet to avoid dependent package installation and give more user friendliness and make the application platform independent.

I have already gone through the following link -

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html

According to this link I need a privileged applet to do system related activities.

My Questions are -

1. Is is at all a good idea to use applets for what I need to implement?
2. How to make applets privileged?
3. Does applets work on Android or iOS? AFAIK, JRE is not available for these two platforms.
4. Can I go for JNLP API? Is that platform independent? I found some examples here - http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#fs

Thanks

Comment: Use Applet - I wouldn't.  It's still possible, even with a signed Applet for the end user to reject the privileges you need.  Better to use a simple stand alone application - IMHO

Answer (score 1):

> Is is at all a good idea to use applets for what I need to implement?

No.  Applets are a PITA to develop **or** maintain.

Do as advised by MadProgrammer and use a stand alone application.

> How to make applets privileged?

Digitally sign them, then encourage the user to click OK when prompted.

> Does applets work on Android or iOS?

No.

> Can I go for JNLP API? Is that platform independent?

The JNLP API is available to desktop apps. and applets running in JSE (so again not iOS or Android).

---

There is no x-plat language that can cover all required platforms.  I'd use Java for desktops & Android API for Android phones.  I don't know what iOS is programmed in.